# Book about an apartment building with a malevolent intelligence in the basement

Tags: story-identification, novel

An apartment building with a malevolent intelligence in the basement.  It includes a rhyme - "I chased A bug around a tree, I'll have his blood, he knows I will"

I had the book around about 1972, it had a black and white patterned dustjacket.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found the story in question. It's a [fairly common schoolyard rhyme](https://www.bubblews.com/news/3575084-i-chased-a-bug-around-a-tree). Unless this is you, [someone else is also seeking this](https://deaconbarry.blogspot.com/2007/02/i-chased-bug-around-tree.html). Closest match I've found is ''[Tommy Remembered](https://books.google.com/books?id=mnK6SjqKwUUC&pg=PA57&vq=chased%20a%20bug&dq=i%20chased%20a%20bug%20around%20a%20tree&output=html_text&source=gbs_search_r&cad=1)'' which references the line, but that's almost certainly not the right story as what I've read of it makes it out to be a completely mundane slice-of-life story.